# React sends me to 404 when route exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .htaccess

I have my website that contains routes, once you click button, it sends you to `/start` route.

**It works fine in localhost** - which suspicious for htaccess, but in my server it's routing to `/start` and return 404.

The PHP code works, because it meant to send me email and it sends me (also in my server hosting), but only the routing doesn't work.

```
fetch('https://devcore.co.il/server/mail.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    redirect: 'follow',
    body: new URLSearchParams(formData)
})
.then(function(response) {
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        return response.text()
    }
    throw new Error(response.statusText)
})
.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    if(response === 'success'){
        history.push("/start");
        history.go(0);
        executeScroll();
    }
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I have used fetch to apply the page routing, works fine in localhost.

**HTACCESS**

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Content-Type "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Accept "*"
    # This should enable the authentication header
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
</IfModule>
```

My route

```
<Route path="/start">
  //Implementing my `/start` route
</Route>
```

What causing the page go 404 on server hosting but work on localhost?

Comment: The `.htaccess` file you posted isn't really doing anything, so how are requests expected to be routed through React? "It works fine in localhost - which suspicious for htaccess" - what do you mean by "with suspicious for htaccess`? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files or directives on localhost?

Comment: @MrWhite I don't have any other htaccess, the htaccess part here is to get the fetch working, so it will route to `/start`, but right now `/start` returns 404 on my server hosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever we build our react application into production mode the routes goes like this (something.com/index.html/route-path) in apache or nginx server so we have to rewrite the path by skipping index.html. Try this configuration.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I will be glad if you can provide more information about why that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I have found placing the history.push call is very tricky. Is there another place you could have that method call? I usually put it in the button onClick section.

```
onClick={() => {
console.log("Button clicked");
other methods calls...;
history.push("/start");
}}
```

However, this will require you set up the history const in each component, so maybe not the cleanest solution. This is the best I can offer.
If you find a way to have conditional history.push calls based on the response.status I will be very interested and jealous.

Comment: Basically what I did worked, I have used response to fetch the data (whether the mail succeed or failed), echoed the answer, so I can use conditional `history.push` calls based on those responses.